# Angular filter returning an array of objects causing infinite $digest loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, infinite-loop

I have a custom filter which returns an array of matches to search field input and it works, but only after causing an infinite $digest loop. This also apparently only began happening after upgrading from Angular 1.0.6. This is the filter code:

```
angular.module("Directory.searches.filters", [])
.filter('highlightMatches', function() {
  var ary = [];
  return function (obj, matcher) {
    if (matcher && matcher.length) {
      var regex = new RegExp("(\\w*" + matcher + "\\w*)", 'ig');
      ary.length = 0;
      angular.forEach(obj, function (object) {
        if (object.text.match(regex)) {
          ary.push(angular.copy(object));
          ary[ary.length-1].text = object.text.replace(regex, "<em>$1</em>");
        }
      });
      return ary;
    } else  {
      return obj;
    }
  }
});
```

I've seen elsewhere that this could be caused by having the filter inside of an ng-show, or that it's because the array being returned is interpreted as a new array every time it's checked, but I'm not sure how I could fix either problem. You can see a production example of this issue at https://www.popuparchive.com/collections/514/items/4859 and the open source project is available at https://github.com/PRX/pop-up-archive. Thank you!

Comment: can you post the code where this filter is used?

Comment: I think it's because of `angular.copy(object)`. Each time the digest cycle runs, the filter returns an array of new objects that angular has never seen before, so the the digest loop goes on forever.

Comment: @AnthonyChu Thanks! Do you have a suggestion for how I might refactor this function to avoid that problem?

Comment: @Prasad It's written in Slim and I keep getting parser errors when I try to convert to HTML because of the Angular syntax, so unfortunately the easiest way to see the context is to follow that link I posted and inspect the transcript elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of `angular.copy(object)`. Each time the digest cycle runs, the filter returns an array of new objects that angular has never seen before, so the the digest loop goes on forever.

One solution is return an array containing the original items that match the filter, with a `highlightedText` property added to each item...

```
angular.module("Directory.searches.filters", [])
.filter('highlightMatches', function() {
  return function (items, matcher) {
    if (matcher && matcher.length) {
      var filteredItems = [];
      var regex = new RegExp("(\\w*" + matcher + "\\w*)", 'ig');
      angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
        if (item.text.match(regex)) {
          item.highlightedText = item.text.replace(regex, "<em>$1</em>");
          filteredItems.push(item);
        }
      });
      return filteredItems;
    } else  {
      angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
        item.highlightedText = item.text;
      });
      return items;
    }
  }
});
```

You can bind to the `highlightedText` property, something like...

```
<div>
    Results
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items | highlightMatches : matcher" ng-bind-html="item.highlightedText"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```